# Loading time of image so long on my page, improvements?

Tags: css, html

My webpage load some news article from severals news feed. When the parsing is complete, the prupose is to create a line with 4 articles side by side and to show the image associated to the article.

Everthing works fine, but the loading time is verry long. Maybe, i have done a mistake or an improvement should be found on my code..

Could you help me please ?

[EDIT]

Screenshot of network tab :

[image]

Here is the result :

[image]

And here is the loop which allows to create this interface :

```
if (jsonObj.news) {

                $('body').css('background', '#171717');

                // Model for create div news element
                function appendModel(news, lineToAppend) {
                    if (news) {
                        if (news.img.indexOf("-/http") !== -1) {
                            news.img = news.img.substring(news.img.indexOf("-/http")+2, news.img.length) ;
                        }
                        var model = '<div class="item"><div class="img-div"><img id="item_img" src="' + news.img + '" /></div><h2 id="item_text"><span id="dateNews">' + news.date.substring(5,16) + ' by </span><span id="sourceNews">' + news.from + '</span><img src="src/ui_template_demo_news/img/ic_action_share.png" class="sharingIcon" /><span id="titleNews">' + news.title + '</span><span id="urlHidden">' + news.link +'</span></h2></div>';
                        lineToAppend.append(model);
                    }
                }

                // New stuff
                var lineCount = parseInt(jsonObj.news.length / 4);
                for (var j=0; j<lineCount; j++) {
                    var line = $('<div id="line'+(j+1)+'"></div>');

                    for (var i=0; i<4 ; i++) {
                        appendModel(jsonObj.news[j*4 + i], line);
                    }

                    $(line).appendTo($('#content'));
                }

                var allLines = $('div[id*=line]') ;
                for (var i=1; i<allLines.length ; i++) {
                    $(allLines[i]).css("display", "flex");
                    $(allLines[i]).css("margin-top", "15px");
                }

            }
```

Comment: There are many potential reasons for a long load time (e.g. image size, dns lookup, ...). For usability reasons i'd suggest you to add a loading indicator. Additonally you should give us some more info like: A screenshot of your network tab (in web developer tools), the size of the images, etc. Your code seems okay.

Comment: @Sven I have added a screnshot of network tab. It seems that the browser try to load each image severals times..

Comment: I would definitely use a CDN (cloudflare.com) and see if you can somehow crop and/or resize the images to a smaller size to use those as thumbnails and show the original size image when an article is clicked.

Comment: @user3608176 It could be a solution. Maybe i can found a script to crop / resize each image before setting in <img> tag

Comment: If it's with PHP you can use the ImageManipulator script https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506 And a tutorial on using this script can be found here http://www.codeforest.net/upload-crop-and-resize-images-with-php

Comment: @wawanopoulos You should really preload the images once to prevent the multiple loading behaviour. This also results in an improved usability and multiple image occurrences without reloading them.